# Нет линка на портах

Tags: свич

Свич новый, пробросил виланы, оптические порты работают, а вот 4 медных не хотят даже линковаться, пробовал и с гигабитными и со 100 мегабитными портами его подключать.

свич ZTE zxr10 5928.

И еще почему-то нету там range, не могу все порты выделить, приходилось виланы на каждый отдельно пробрасывать. interface gei_1/1-24 не хочет тоже работать, может кто знает как?

И последний вопрос, может кто сталкивался с такими свичами и помог бы мне на нем LACP настроить, а то интерфейс похожий на cisco, но есть несовпадения.

Answer (score 1):

а если попытаться загнать все медные пары в один ВЛАН ?

Comment: они и так на одном вилане, а при чем тут влан?но я уже разобрался:         interface gei_1/21            hybrid-attribute copper